# Swiping to another textview

Tags: android

Well, I've got two TextViews, lets call the first one "**A**" and the second one "**B**".
I'm trying to make a "text slider", which makes you able to switch from **A** to **B** by gestures (swipe the finger to the left if you'd like to see TextView **A**, you've got the TextView **B** visible, and swipe the finger to the right if you'd like to see TextView **B**, incase you've got the TextView **A** visible.)

What's the best approach on "making this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ViewPager for this.
[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: I'm probably the biggest newbie in Android SDK "programming" >_<. I did test this, but I can't seem to find the ViewPager in the UI "editor", um, is it even located there?

Comment: You can find the ViewPager in the Android Support Library. `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. Here you can find an example of using: [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Sorry, here is a better tutorial, which does not use fragments, but only texts and images. This is better for you. [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/)